# How to Return Value in Pass-Through Function (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, callback, promise

I am trying to set a variable in a parent function to a imported and nested function in Node.

**Parent**

```
const child = require('./child')

function init() {
  second()
  let def = abc
  console.log(def) // Expected log: 15
                   // Actual log: abc is not defined
}

function second() {
  return child.third()
}

init()
```

**Child**

```
exports.third = () => {
  let abc = 15
  return abc
}
```

How do I properly return the value of `abc` so it can be set and logged in `init()`?

Comment: why do you not simply do abc = second() in your init() block? am I missing something?

Comment: Nope. That works.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply do `abc = second()` in your `init()` block

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't get your question but in order to include anything you need first export it.

```
function third() {
  let abc = 15
  return abc
}
module.exports = {
    third
};
```

Now, you just need to import the file and invoke the function

```
const child = require('child')

function init() {
  let def = second();
  console.log(def) // Expected log: 15
}

function second() {
  return child.third()
}

init()
```